# Android: send mail with Outlook not show text

Tags: android, email, text, gmail, send

I have created a app with sends of mails with a form. It works fine with Gmail. But if I choose Outlook, the field Text appears empty, while the subject and address appears with text.

Why does that outlook?

```
private void sendMail(String[] address, String subject, String text) {

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));

    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, address);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(text));

    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email "));
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating Html from text then changing it back to String?

Comment: Because my text has bold, underline...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem is solved. I have deleted `Html.fromHtml(...)` and it works fine.